# Hiberate criteria - OR between criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a table Prod, which has 3 fk relationships with table User:

```
Prod
-----
id
user_id_1
user_id_2
user_id_3

User
-----
id
firstname
lastname
```

Given a possible <*firstname*> and <*lastname*> on a search form, I would like to do something like (pseudocode):

```
Find all Prod 
where
(user_id_1.firstname like <firstname> AND user_id_1.lastname like <lastname>) OR
(user_id_2.firstname like <firstname> AND user_id_2.lastname like <lastname>) OR
(user_id_3.firstname like <firstname> AND user_id_3.lastname like <lastname>)
```

With Hibernate's Criteria objects, I believe the way to perform association table operations is with an additional Criteria object:

```
Criteria prodCriteria = session.createCriteria(Prod.class);
Criteria user1Criteria = prodCriteria.createCriteria("userId1");
LogicalExpression user1Le = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ilike("firstame", <firstname>, MatchMode.ANYWHERE), Restrictions.ilike("lastname", <lastname>, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
user1Criteria.add(user1Le);

Criteria user2Criteria = prodCriteria.createCriteria("userId2");
LogicalExpression user2Le = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ilike("firstame", <firstname>, MatchMode.ANYWHERE), Restrictions.ilike("lastname", <lastname>, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
user2Criteria.add(user2Le);

Criteria user3Criteria = prodCriteria.createCriteria("userId3");
LogicalExpression user3Le = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ilike("firstame", <firstname>, MatchMode.ANYWHERE), Restrictions.ilike("lastname", <lastname>, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
user3Criteria.add(user3Le);
```

However, doesn't this produce AND's between the association *sub-criteria* objects where I want OR's?

Is there a way to perform OR's between *sub-criteria* objects?  Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using explicit aliases:

```java
Criterion criterionUser1 = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ilike("user1.firstname", firstname, MatchMode.ANYWHERE),
                Restrictions.ilike("user1.lastname", lastname, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
Criterion criterionUser2 = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ilike("user2.firstname", firstname, MatchMode.ANYWHERE),
                Restrictions.ilike("user2.lastname", lastname, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
Criterion criterionUser3 = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ilike("user3.firstname", firstname, MatchMode.ANYWHERE),
                Restrictions.ilike("user3.lastname", lastname, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

        Criteria prodCriteria2 = session
                                    .createCriteria(Prod.class)
                                    .createAlias("userId1", "user1")
                                    .createAlias("userId2", "user2")
                                    .createAlias("userId3", "user3")
                                    .add(Restrictions.or(criterionUser1, criterionUser2, criterionUser3));
```